# External Monitor Issues with a Dell Inspiron 1300

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-display

I just recently bought a high def tv and I want to use it as an external monitor.  The tv tech support told me that the resolution settings that my laptop offers are suppose to work, but maybe my hsync, vsync, and pixel frequency might be off.  I was wondering, if anyone knew how to change/see those values and correct them?

I have a Dell Inspiron 1300 and it outputs 800x600, 1024x768, 1400x900, and a few others less than 1920x1080.

My tv accepts 640x480, 800x600, 1024x768, 1360x768, and 1920x1080.
I was told that for the tv's 1024x768 @ 75hz the hsync should be 60.023, the vsync should be 75.026, and the pixel frequency should be 78.75.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.  I had to change the way it was being presented.  I eliminated the border off of my screen and it worked like a charm.